# react-native-router-flux, how to detect router change?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to make analytics logging for screen view whenever the router changed.
I am using react-native-router-flux but it seems there is no way to detect that in the guide?
Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks in advance!

Like below

```js
if (routerChanged) {
  analytics().logScreenView({
    screen_name: currentRouteName,
    screen_class: currentRouteName,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this. [react-native-router-flux API](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/API.md)

Worked for me with **onStateChange** prop function in **Router** component.

```js
import { Actions, Router, Scene, Stack } from "react-native-router-flux";

<Router
  onStateChange={(e) => {
    console.log("Current screen___", e.routes[e.routes.length - 1].routeName);
    console.log("Current screen___", Actions.currentScene);
  }}
>
  ...
</Router>
```